# Normalizing a histogram in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a histogram

```
hist(A, 801)
```

that currently resembles a normal curve but with max value at y = 1500, and mean at x = 0.5. I want to normalize it, so I tried

```
h = hist(A, 801)
h = h ./ sum(h)
bar(h)
```

now I get a normal curve with max at y = .03, but a mean at x = 450.

how do I decrease the frequency so the sum is 1, while retaining the same x range?

A is derived from

```
A = walk(50000, 800, .05, 2, .25, 0)
```

where

```
function [X_new] = walk(N_sim, N, mu, T, sigma, X_init)

delt = T/N;
up = sigma*sqrt(delt);
down = -sigma*sqrt(delt);

p = 1./2.*(1.+mu/sigma*sqrt(delt));

X_new = zeros(N_sim,1);
X_new(1:N_sim,1) = X_init;

ptest = zeros(N_sim,1);

for i = 1:N

    ptest(:,1) = rand(N_sim,1);
    ptest(:,1) = (ptest(:,1) <= p);

    X_new(:,1) = X_new(:,1) + ptest(:,1)*up + (1.-ptest(:,1))*down;

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum is 1 with your code as it stands.

You may want *integral* equal to 1 (so that you can compare with the theoretical pdf). In that case:

```
[h, c] = hist(A, 801); %// c contains bin centers. They are equally spaced
h = h / sum(h) / (c(2)-c(1)); %// normalize to area 1
trapz(c,h) %// compute integral. Should be approximately 1
```

Comment: trapz(c, h) is 1 but when I try to plot it with bar(c, h) the max value is around y = 45

Comment: You need to be more specific. Why is it a problem that the max is at y=45? Can you provide data that reproduce your problem?

Comment: i am trying to make the sum under the curve to be 1

Comment: I bet the plotted area is 1. _How_ do you know it's more than 1? How are you visually assessing the area?

Comment: the max value is over 8 which is way too high for an area of 1 with sigma around .5

Comment: i'm guessing there is something wrong with the way the bar() function presents the graph

Comment: As a said, you should post example data that reproduces the problem. Otherwise it's hard to tell what's wrong

Comment: A = walk(50000, 800, .25, 2, .05, 0)

Comment: and so that's how A is derived and when I follow the steps you have shown, trapz(c, h) is 1 but the bar graph's area is a lot more

Comment: Come on! Edit your question directly; long code can't be read in comments. And post the figure too

Comment: sorry, i'm not very familiar with SO, i have editted the question, thanks

Comment: No problem! I think I see what the issue is: if you use `stem(c,h)` instead of `bar(c,h)` you'll see there are many bars of zero height. So the area is 1 but it seems to be more because those zero-height bars are not seen

Comment: Or just changing 801 to say 81 removes thoese zero-heights bars, and now the area _looks_ about 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62425/discussion-between-jackery-xu-and-luis-mendo).